# Atomic Transactions in EF Core and Postgres

Tags: c#, postgresql, transactions, entity-framework-core

I have a Postgres database which gets filled with tasks and a programm that retrieves them and processes them.
Right now i retrieve this way:

```
                    var tasks = await _context.Tasks
                        .Where(t => t.status== Status.New)
                        .OrderBy(t => t.StartTime)
                        .Take(maxAmount)
                        .ToListAsync();
                    tasks.ForEach((t) => t.status= Status.Launched);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Now I want to make it runnable in parallel, at first in multiple threads and later in multiple instances maybe on different machines.
What I tried is using an transaction like this:

```
            var strategy = _context.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy();
            return await strategy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
            {
                using var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction();
                try
                {
                    var tasks = await _context.Tasks
                        .Where(t => t.status== Status.New)
                        .OrderBy(t => t.StartTime)
                        .Take(maxAmount)
                        .ToListAsync();
                    tasks.ForEach((t) => t.status= Status.Launched);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    await transaction.CommitAsync();
                    return tasks;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    await transaction.RollbackAsync();
                    throw e;
                }
            });
```

But it seems to not work because I get sometimes errors with duplicate entries when trying to write back the result later, so it looks like 2 threads are processing the same task. Is there a more elegant way to do something like that?
Like updating the state and returning in an atomic way?
Or some totally different approach that is actually state of the art for problems like this?

Comment: Maybe causing race condition. Lock a row before update. This feature is DB engine specific. You can make an idea to distribute the rows to the threads(servers) without duplication. If your data is an unique logged in end-user, you don't have to query for all rows in a thread(server). Instead, process by the currently login server(thread).